# Не могу вызвать Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Ребят всем привет. Такая проблемка. Есть метод внутри активности:

```
public class Registrations extends AppCompatActivity {

Registrations registrations;
Intent intent;

private Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrations);
    setTitle("");

    this.activity = this;
}


public void uploadMultipart(final Context context, final String name, final String lname, int id) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject data = dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("data");

                try {
                    String error = data.getString("error");
                    String error_msg = data.getString("error_msg");

                    if(error.equals("0")) {
                        intent = new Intent(Registrations.this, MainActivity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);   
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ve) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ve.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("ava", imageToString(bitmap));
            return hashMap;
        }
    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

После того как приходит ответ от сервера о том что ошибок нет, я хочу переадресовать юзера на другую активность, но почему то срабатывает исключение:

```
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.admin.myapplication.auth.Registrations$3.onResponse(Registrations.java:136)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.admin.myapplication.auth.Registrations$3.onResponse(Registrations.java:118)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
10-28 18:20:28.454 2188-2188/com.example.admin.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

В чём проблема подскажите пожалуйста?

```
public class RegistrationsPOST extends Registrations {

private int id;
private String name;
private String lname;
private String pass;
private String re_pass;
private String number;
private String email;

private Toast toast;
private String LOG_TAG = "RegistrationsPOST";
private Context context;
private Activity mainActivity;

Authorizations authorizations;
AuthSuccess as;


public RegistrationsPOST(Activity activity, String name, String lname,
                         String pass, String re_pass, String number, String email) {

    this.mainActivity = activity;
    this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    this.name = name;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.email = email;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.number = number;
    this.re_pass = re_pass;


    UserDataLoad userDataLoad = new UserDataLoad();
    userDataLoad.execute();
    authorizations = new Authorizations();
    as = new AuthSuccess();
}


class UserDataLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private StringRequest request;
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "URL", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
                try {
                    dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject data = dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("data");

                    try {
                        String error = data.getString("error");
                        String error_msg = data.getString("error_msg");

                        if(error.equals("1")) {
                            toast = Toast.makeText(context, error_msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.show();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        id = data.getInt("id");
                        name = data.getString("name");
                        lname = data.getString("lname");
                        uploadMultipart(context, name, lname, id); 
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, response);
            }
```

}

Comment: А `uploadMultipart` вы откуда и как вызываете?

Comment: С анонимного класса, наследуясь от этой активити.

Comment: Вы там `onCreate` метод, случайно, не переопределяете? Если переопределяете, то `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` вызываете?

Comment: Нет, не переопределял ничего. В анонимном классе тоже сетевой запрос находится. Через AsyncTask

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос. Добавил туда тот самый анонимный класс.

Comment: Эм. Вы, случаем экземпляр класса `RegistrationsPOST` не через `new` созадёте? Если да, то не надо так делать. У вас в таком случае `onCreate` не будет вызван. `Activity` нельзя через `new` создавать.

Comment: Ну так RegistrationsPOST не является активностью. Активностью является Registrations

Comment: Является. Вы же его унаследовали от `Registrations`, который является активностью. Следовательно, и `RegistrationsPOST` является активностью.

Comment: Ага...понял. Тогда в принципе не вижу смысла его наследовать. Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его как принятый. Если будут другие проблемы, то лучше задавать их отдельным вопросом ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверняка можно было бы сказать, если бы вы показали код работы с переменной `activity`. Но, очевидно, у вас `activity` равен `null`.

**UPD**: судя по всему, вы создаёте экземпляр класса активности `RegistrationsPOST` через `new`. Как следствие, не вызывается `onCreate` вашего базового класса `Registrations`, где вы присваиваете этой ссылке значение.

В Android нельзя создавать классы активностей через `new`.

Comment: private Activity activity, в методе onCreate() { activity.this }

Comment: @sergei1094 это объявление, да. Переменная равна `null` А как и где вы её инициализируете? Лучше добавить это в вопрос.

Comment: В методе onCreate разве не игициализирую?

Comment: @sergei1094 само? Нет. Пока вы явно этого сами не сделаете.

Comment: activity.this - тут же инициализирую

Comment: @sergei1094 так `this.activity = this;`? Добавьте эту часть в вопрос.

Comment: Нет, сделал так: activity.this

Comment: @sergei1094 `activity.this` ничего не делает. Просто возвращает ссылку. Напишите вместо этого `this.activity = this;`.

Comment: Упс ошибся, не activity.this а activity = this)

Comment: Использовал - this.activity = this; Всё равно null возвращает.

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос, пожалуйста посмотрите.